# Firebase Path Specified Exceeds Maximum Depth that Can Be Written

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write to Firebase via the code below:

```
  mSubmitPollCreation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //TODO: Need to determine if this is proper epoch - i.e. does it account for time zones
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            final String epochTime = String.valueOf(c.getTimeInMillis());
            mEpochRef = mBaseRef.child("Polls").child(epochTime);

            //TODO: Need to check if poll requirements are added, i.e. Question, Answer, ......
            //check if image has been loaded first
            if (resultImageURL != null){
                Map<String, Object> imageURL = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                imageURL.put("Image_URL", imageURL);
                mEpochRef.setValue(imageURL);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.no_image_selected),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
     });
```

And I unsure why I am receiving the following error:

```
   Process: com.troychuinard.fanpolls, PID: 6409
                                                               com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Path specified exceeds the maximum depth that can be written (32) or object contains a cycle in path 'Polls/1481160966268/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL/Image_URL'
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzcms(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzsx(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zzbs(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajo.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.CreateActivity$2.onClick(CreateActivity.java:103)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21294)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

It looks like for some reason my code is looping through creating the database point, however I am unsure why it is doing this.

Comment: The problem is that you have initialized **imageURL** without having data inside it.
You are passing the reference of the object only.
**Solution** : 
Put some data inside **imageURL**.

Answer (score 2):

I think you intended this:

```
imageURL.put("Image_URL", resultImageURL);
```

instead of this:

```
imageURL.put("Image_URL", imageURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this `task.getResult()` use this `task.getResult().toString()` for storing locally.